# javascript global variable undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a javascript global variable, let's suppose I have the following

```
var globalVar;
```

I have a text field

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeydown="checkKey(this)" onkeypress="checkKey(this)"/>
```

And in the function checkkey, I assign some value to it:

```
globalVar=document.forms[0].elements("myInput").value;
```

I checked the the global variable value has changed with an alert.
When I try to use `globalVar` in another function, I find it has the value undefined. The other function has something like:

```
param += globalVar;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `elements` property of `form` instances isn't a function, it's an object. Use

```
globalVar=document.forms[0].elements.myInput.value;
```

...or

```
globalVar=document.forms[0].elements["myInput"].value;
```

...but better yet, with the way you're calling `checkKey`, just declare an argument called `input` or whatever and use

```
globalVar=input.value;
```

...since you're passing `this` into `checkKey`.

If you're going to access the form field by its name as you have, use the `name` attribute rather than the `id` attribute (although `id` will work on many browsers as well).

If your `var globalVar;` is at global scope (outside of all functions), then it is a global variable. If that `var` statement is inside a function, it's a local variable. You haven't given us enough context to know where the `var` is, but if it's at global scope, and you successfully set its value, and later you check it, it *will* be set.

[Live demo using the long form](http://jsbin.com/uwiwec) | [Live demo using the argument](http://jsbin.com/uwiwec/2)

Comment: I said it's a global variable, so it is at global score(outside all functions)...